# Hierarchical queries with Mongo using $graphLookup

Tags: mongodb

I have an employee collection with half a million records. Each record will have the following details.

The mongo document is as follows.

```
{
  "_id": "234463456453643563456",
  "name": "Mike",
  "empId": "10",
  "managerId": "8",
  "projects" : [ "123", "456", "789"]
}
```

1. When i give any empId, it should return the complete hierarchies from that manager to the bottom level along with the following filter.

> a. filter on
>   location
>     b. filter on projects

The result should be like,

```
      10     ->>> Manager
      /\
     /  \
    8    6  ---->> 8 & 6 reporting to manager 10
    /\    /\
   /  \  /  \
  4    5 2   1  ---->> 4 & 5 reporting to manager 8 ...
```

Any help will be appreciated for getting the hierarchical results with level?

I am not able to get the result as expected.

**Sample Data :-**

```
db.getCollection("employees").insert({"_id":"10","empId": "10","name":"Employee10","managerId":"15" });

db.getCollection("employees").insert({"_id":"8","empId": "8","name":"Employee8","managerId":"10" });

db.getCollection("employees").insert({"_id":"6","empId": "6","name":"Employee6","managerId":"10" });

db.getCollection("employees").insert({"_id":"4","empId": "4","name":"Employee4","managerId":"8" });

db.getCollection("employees").insert({"_id":"5","empId": "5","name":"Employee5","managerId":"8" });

db.getCollection("employees").insert({"_id":"2","empId": "2","name":"Employee2","managerId":"6" });

db.getCollection("employees").insert({"_id":"1","empId": "1","name":"Employee1","managerId":"6" });
```

**Query :-**

```
db.getCollection('employees').aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        empId : "10"
    }
},
{
   $graphLookup: {
      from: "employees",
      startWith: "$empId",
      connectFromField: "empId",
      connectToField: "managerId",
      as: "reportees",
      maxDepth: 4,
      depthField: "level"
   }
},
{
   $project: {
     "empId":1,
     "managerId":1,
     "reportees.empId":1,
     "reportees.name":1,
     "reportees.managerId":1,
     "reportees.level":1
   }
}
]);
```

**Actual Result :-**

```
{ 
    "_id" : "10", 
    "empId" : "10", 
    "managerId" : "15", 
    "reportees" : [
        {
            "empId" : "1", 
            "name" : "Employee1", 
            "managerId" : "6", 
            "level" : NumberLong(1)
        }, 
        {
            "empId" : "4", 
            "name" : "Employee4", 
            "managerId" : "8", 
            "level" : NumberLong(1)
        }, 
        {
            "empId" : "2", 
            "name" : "Employee2", 
            "managerId" : "6", 
            "level" : NumberLong(1)
        }, 
        {
            "empId" : "5", 
            "name" : "Employee5", 
            "managerId" : "8", 
            "level" : NumberLong(1)
        }, 
        {
            "empId" : "6", 
            "name" : "Employee6", 
            "managerId" : "10", 
            "level" : NumberLong(0)
        }, 
        {
            "empId" : "8", 
            "name" : "Employee8", 
            "managerId" : "10", 
            "level" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    ]
}
```

**Expected Result :-**

```
{ 
    "_id" : "10", 
    "empId" : "10", 
    "managerId" : "15", 
    "reportees" : [
        {
            "empId" : "6", 
            "name" : "Employee6", 
            "managerId" : "10", 
            "level" : NumberLong(0),
            "reportees" : [
              {
               "empId" : "1", 
               "name" : "Employee1", 
               "managerId" : "6", 
               "level" : NumberLong(1)
              }, 
              {
               "empId" : "2", 
               "name" : "Employee2", 
               "managerId" : "6", 
               "level" : NumberLong(1)
              }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "empId" : "8", 
            "name" : "Employee8", 
            "managerId" : "10", 
            "level" : NumberLong(0),
            "reportees" : [
              {
                "empId" : "5", 
                "name" : "Employee5", 
                "managerId" : "8", 
                "level" : NumberLong(1)
              },
              {
                "empId" : "4", 
                "name" : "Employee4", 
                "managerId" : "8", 
                "level" : NumberLong(1)
              }
             ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Questions :-**

1. Is it possible to get the expected output with $graphLookup?
2. Also, Is it possible to get the count at the top level and also for each sub level?
3. How to apply projection at all level?
4. How to apply filter on top of this?

Comment: @veeram, here's a challenge!

Comment: @chridam, can you help?

Comment: @alexblex, fancy a tough question?

Comment: @anthonywinzlet, come and help!

Comment: @mickl, get in the ring!

Comment: @dnickless I think the only person can help here is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2313887/neil-lunn). Which is himself a mongodb and has(I think) retired now :-).

Comment: @dnickless, entered the ring :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's precicsely what you would [$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) for (the traversal bit at least). For the filtering part you could simply use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) or [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) depending on how exactly you want to filter.

Have a look at the results of this query:

```
db.employees.aggregate({
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "employees",
      startWith: "$managerId",
      connectFromField: "managerId",
      connectToField: "empId",
      as: "managers",
    }
})
```

**UPDATE 1 based on your clarification:**

In order to get the hierarchical structure that you'd like to get you could do the following. However, I wouldn't call this a pretty solution since it requires you statically define the number of levels you want to go down and also to repeat sections but it does the job for your example. Not sure, if/how easily this can be extended to more levels, either. Personally, I think a client side loop solution would be more suitable for this kind of job:

```
db.employees.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        empId : "10"
    }
},
// level 0
{
   $graphLookup: {
      from: "employees",
      startWith: "$empId",
      connectFromField: "empId",
      connectToField: "managerId",
      as: "reportees",
      maxDepth: 0
   }
},
{
    $unwind: "$reportees" // flatten
},
{
    $addFields: {
        "reportees.level": 0 // add level field
    }
},
// level 1
{
   $graphLookup: {
      from: "employees",
      startWith: "$reportees.empId",
      connectFromField: "reportees.empId",
      connectToField: "managerId",
      as: "reportees.reportees",
      maxDepth: 0
   }
},
{
    $group: { // group previously flattened documents back together
        _id: "$_id",
        empId: { $first: "$empId" },
        name: { $first: "$name" },
        managerId: { $first: "$managerId" },
        reportees: { $push: "$reportees" },
    }
},
{
    $addFields: {
        "reportees.reportees.level": 1 // add level field
    }
}
])
```

**UPDATE 2:**

The following query gets you to where you want to be from an output structure point of view (I omitted the `level` field but it should be easy to add). It is, however, not particularly pretty and, again, requires you to define a maximum organisational depth upfront.

```
db.employees.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        empId : "10"
    }
},
{
   $graphLookup: { // get the relevant documents out of our universe of employees
      from: "employees",
      startWith: "$empId",
      connectFromField: "empId",
      connectToField: "managerId",
      as: "reportees"
   }
},
{
    $project: { // add the employee we are interested in into the array of employees we're looking at
        _id: 0,
        reportees: { $concatArrays: [ "$reportees", [ { _id: "$_id", empId: "$empId", name: "$name", managerId: "$managerId" } ] ] }
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        reportees: {
            $let: {
                vars: {
                    managers: {
                        $filter: { // remove employees with no reportess so keep managers only
                            input: {
                                $map: {
                                    input: "$reportees",
                                    as: "this",
                                    in: {
                                        $mergeObjects: [
                                            "$$this",
                                            {
                                                reportees: {
                                                    $filter: { // extract reportees from list of employees
                                                        input: "$reportees",
                                                        as: "that",
                                                        cond: {
                                                            $eq: [ "$$this._id", "$$that.managerId" ]
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            as: "this",
                            cond: { $ne: [ "$$this.reportees", [] ] }
                        }
                    }
                },
                in: {
                    $cond: [ // this is to break the processing once we have reached a top level manager
                        { $eq: [ "$$managers", [] ] },
                        "$reportees",
                        "$$managers"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
// second level: exactly identical to the previous stage
// third level: exactly identical to the previous stage
// basically, from here onwards you would need to repeat an exact copy of the previous stage to go one level deeper
]);
```

Comment: Already tried but not working as expected. Getting hierarchies for each record as opposed to just returning for a given manager I’d.

Comment: You could just add a `$match` stage before the lookup that limits the results to one specific manager!

Comment: It returns all the levels under reportees of first level and returns level correctly as 0 for immediate reportees and 1 for the following, ...

But, I want the result in hierarchical formats.

Comment: So, its not possible with the single query irrespective of levels.

Comment: Well, technically speaking you could have a single query following the `Update 2` pattern which caters for 100 levels or so but I admit that this would still be a limitation and probably slow and nasty, too. I cannot think of a different solution at this stage, though. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 16):

I belive that having **level** field we can build hierarchical structure from an array using [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/). To achieve that we need to get `reportees` ordered by level descending after `$graphLookup`. Unfortunately the only way to do it currently is to use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) + [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) + [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) which makes the aggregation quite long.

Then we can process that ordered array using `$reduce`. In each step we just have to add an employee to the result set including his `reportees` from previous level. Additionally we need to detect when `level` changes during our processing and rearrange helper arrays in that case.

[$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) simply replaces existing `reportees` field in this case. [$concatArrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/index.html) allows us to append current employee (`$$this`) to the result. Using [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) we can get `reportees` from lower level.

```
db.getCollection('employees').aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            empId : "10"
        }
    },
    {
        $graphLookup: {
            from: "employees",
            startWith: "$empId",
            connectFromField: "empId",
            connectToField: "managerId",
            as: "reportees",
            maxDepth: 4,
            depthField: "level"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "empId":1,
            "managerId":1,
            "reportees.empId":1,
            "reportees.name":1,
            "reportees.managerId":1,
            "reportees.level":1
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$reportees"
    },
    {
        $sort: { "reportees.level": -1 }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            empId: { $first: "$empId" },
            managerId: { $first: "$managerId" },
            reportees: { $push: "$reportees" }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            reportees: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$reportees",
                    initialValue: {
                        currentLevel: -1,
                        currentLevelEmployees: [],
                        previousLevelEmployees: []
                    },
                    in: {
                        $let: {
                            vars: {
                                prev: { 
                                    $cond: [ 
                                        { $eq: [ "$$value.currentLevel", "$$this.level" ] }, 
                                        "$$value.previousLevelEmployees", 
                                        "$$value.currentLevelEmployees" 
                                    ] 
                                },
                                current: { 
                                    $cond: [ 
                                        { $eq: [ "$$value.currentLevel", "$$this.level" ] }, 
                                        "$$value.currentLevelEmployees", 
                                        [] 
                                    ] 
                                }
                            },
                            in: {
                                currentLevel: "$$this.level",
                                previousLevelEmployees: "$$prev",
                                currentLevelEmployees: {
                                    $concatArrays: [
                                        "$$current", 
                                        [
                                            { $mergeObjects: [ 
                                                "$$this", 
                                                { reportees: { $filter: { input: "$$prev", as: "e", cond: { $eq: [ "$$e.managerId", "$$this.empId"  ] } } } } 
                                            ] }
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: { reportees: "$reportees.currentLevelEmployees" }
    }
]).pretty()
```

Above solution should work for multiple levels. Outputs:

```
{
    "_id" : "10",
    "empId" : "10",
    "managerId" : "15",
    "reportees" : [
        {
            "empId" : "6",
            "name" : "Employee6",
            "managerId" : "10",
            "level" : NumberLong(0),
            "reportees" : [
                {
                        "empId" : "1",
                        "name" : "Employee1",
                        "managerId" : "6",
                        "level" : NumberLong(1),
                        "reportees" : [ ]
                },
                {
                        "empId" : "2",
                        "name" : "Employee2",
                        "managerId" : "6",
                        "level" : NumberLong(1),
                        "reportees" : [ ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "empId" : "8",
            "name" : "Employee8",
            "managerId" : "10",
            "level" : NumberLong(0),
            "reportees" : [
                {
                    "empId" : "5",
                    "name" : "Employee5",
                    "managerId" : "8",
                    "level" : NumberLong(1),
                    "reportees" : [ ]
                },
                {
                    "empId" : "4",
                    "name" : "Employee4",
                    "managerId" : "8",
                    "level" : NumberLong(1),
                    "reportees" : [ ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Utter magic!!! I forgot about that `depthField` parameter... I shall review and award that happily should there not be hidden surprises (or better ideas even)...

Comment: This is the perfect answer!!. It saves my day. any idea about the performance of this query when we've millions of records in the collection?

Comment: @NishchitDhanani haven't been tested but you're welcome to test it on your dataset and share your results here :)

Comment: This works fine, but one glitch, when you have a manager without anyone to report to him, it will not list in the response. any suggestion ,

Comment: Figured it our, by changing the unwind block we can get parent node which do not have child node, like below
      {
          $unwind: {
            path: "$reportees",
            includeArrayIndex: "arrayIndex",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
          }
      }

Answer (score 0):

If using Node.js, a simpler solution is to use mongoose and the populate feature. I answered it here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69017771/2956628

Answer (score -1):

The official documentation on $graphLookup may provide help more or less.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/

Just a kind remind.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I already verified this not much helpful.