# MongoDB $graphLookup - is it possible to get the result in a nested document?

Tags: mongodb, graphlookup

I have a tree structure where each document points to its children.

Then I would like to perform a $graphLookup in some node, and get the nodes N levels down… But instead of getting the result in a list or array, I would like to get a nested document.

Is it possible to do this, some how?

**Edited:**

As an example, let's take the case from the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/#within-a-single-collection):

The collection employees has the following documents:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Dev" }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Eliot", "reportsTo" : "Dev" }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "Ron", "reportsTo" : "Eliot" }
{ "_id" : 4, "name" : "Andrew", "reportsTo" : "Eliot" }
{ "_id" : 5, "name" : "Asya", "reportsTo" : "Ron" }
{ "_id" : 6, "name" : "Dan", "reportsTo" : "Andrew" }
```

The operation performed is:

```
db.employees.aggregate( [
   {
      $graphLookup: {
         from: "employees",
         startWith: "$reportsTo",
         connectFromField: "reportsTo",
         connectToField: "name",
         as: "reportingHierarchy"
      }
   }
] )
```

And the result is:

```
{
   "_id" : 1,
   "name" : "Dev",
   "reportingHierarchy" : [ ]
}
{
   "_id" : 2,
   "name" : "Eliot",
   "reportsTo" : "Dev",
   "reportingHierarchy" : [
      { "_id" : 1, "name" : "Dev" }
   ]
}
{
   "_id" : 3,
   "name" : "Ron",
   "reportsTo" : "Eliot",
   "reportingHierarchy" : [
      { "_id" : 1, "name" : "Dev" },
      { "_id" : 2, "name" : "Eliot", "reportsTo" : "Dev" }
   ]
}
{
   "_id" : 4,
   "name" : "Andrew",
   "reportsTo" : "Eliot",
   "reportingHierarchy" : [
      { "_id" : 1, "name" : "Dev" },
      { "_id" : 2, "name" : "Eliot", "reportsTo" : "Dev" }
   ]
}
{
   "_id" : 5,
   "name" : "Asya",
   "reportsTo" : "Ron",
   "reportingHierarchy" : [
      { "_id" : 1, "name" : "Dev" },
      { "_id" : 2, "name" : "Eliot", "reportsTo" : "Dev" },
      { "_id" : 3, "name" : "Ron", "reportsTo" : "Eliot" }
   ]
}
{
   "_id" : 6,
   "name" : "Dan",
   "reportsTo" : "Andrew",
   "reportingHierarchy" : [
      { "_id" : 1, "name" : "Dev" },
      { "_id" : 2, "name" : "Eliot", "reportsTo" : "Dev" },
      { "_id" : 4, "name" : "Andrew", "reportsTo" : "Eliot" }
   ]
}
```

But let's say I would like the result in the form of a nested document instead of a list, like:

```
Dev
|-- Eliot
    |-- Ron
        |-- Asya
    |-- Andrew
        |--Dan
```

**Edit 2**

It doesn't matter much if the children are in an array or not. Any of the following would be ok, as long as the complete structure is nested:

```
{ 
  "_id" : 1, 
  "name" : "Dev",
  "children" : [
    {
       "_id" : 1, 
       "name" : "Eliot",
       "children": [...]
    }
  ]
}

{ 
  "_id" : 1, 
  "name" : "Dev",
  "children" : {
    {
       "_id" : 1, 
       "name" : "Eliot",
       "children": {...}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the output you're getting and the one you would like to get ?

Comment: I've updated the question with an example

Comment: for further clarification, could you update the expected results as a sample document?

Comment: I have just updated

Comment: @JoãoOtero you can take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52433933/hierarchical-queries-with-mongo-using-graphlookup/52662426#52662426

Comment: perfect @mickl! exactly what I needed, thank you